# How to paste autosuggested code from keyboard in different text input field -Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Currently, the issue is clicking on autosuggested text only filling the first textinput box, I want to fill all the six text inputs with the suggested code

Autosuggested Keyboard screen shot:
[image]

On clicking the autosuggested text, it is only filling first

[image]

Expected behaviour is to fill all the textinputs once user clicks on autosuggested code

Answer (score 1):

kindly check  if android:maxLength="1" is set on first otp edittext then change it in to  android:maxLength="6" (OTP length)

and write this with in onViewCreated in case of fragment
binding.customOTPView1.edt1.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

```
           // Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"otpType = $s == ${s.length} qqq",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


          }


        override fun beforeTextChanged(
            s: CharSequence, start: Int,
            count: Int, after: Int
        ) {

          //  Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"otpType = $s == ${s.length} wwww",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(
            s: CharSequence, start: Int,
            before: Int, count: Int
        ) {
         //  Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"otpType = $s ==  ${s.length} eeeee" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            if (s.length >= 4) {

                binding.customOTPView1.edt1.setText(s[0].toString())
                binding.customOTPView1.edt2.setText(s[1].toString())
                binding.customOTPView1.edt3.setText(s[2].toString())
                binding.customOTPView1.edt4.setText(s[3].toString())
            } else {
               
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a less explored use-case on StackOverflow, but, when you read Android docs for Auto-fill, in the [OTP](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize#one-time_password_otp) section, they have already provided [`generateSmsOtpHintForCharacterPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/autofill/HintConstants#generateSmsOtpHintForCharacterPosition(int)) which states and I quote:

> When using multiple views where each view maps to a single digit of
> the OTP, you can use the generateSmsOptHintForCharacterPosition()
> method to generate per-character hints.

You can utilize the `characterPosition` parameter to auto-fill each `EditText` with the respective digit of the OTP auto-filled.

To do that, set

```
//Where Character Position (int) represents the digit position of the OTP for respective EditText, ranges from 1 to 8.
android:autofillHint="smsOTPCode{characterPosition}"
```

Comment: I tried using android:autofillHints="smsOTPCode{characterPosition}"
                android:importantForAutofill="yes"  and characterPosition gave from 1 to 6 for every editText . Didn't worked for me